How to plot a graph to fit well a certain ratio?
I want to plot my graph in a certain ratio(2:1), for example, 400*200(Width * Height).
I tried ImageSize:
GraphPlot[{2 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 3, 
  5 -> 4}, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 ImageSize -> {400, 200}]

And outputs:

Mathematica just put my graph in the middle of the picture and it doesn't fit well
And then I tried ImageRotate and ImageResize:
ImageResize[
 ImageRotate[
  GraphPlot[{2 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 3, 
    5 -> 4}, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
  90 Degree], {400, 200}]


But the label is rotated also.
How can I output my graph in a 400*200 picture and fit well?
Edit:
GraphPlot[{2 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 3, 
  5 -> 4}, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]


It appears to fit but in a strange way. I want to make it better and like this:


AspectRatio?

AspectRatio -> 1

You need AspectRatio -> 1/2

@MarcoB Can you check my edit?

You need a different embedding method. E.g.: GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding"


we set VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {Left, Bottom}] To make the labels looks good.

we replace all the coordinate {x,y} to {-y, -x} by  {x_Real, y_Real} :>  ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]@RotationMatrix[-(π/2)] . {x, y} to rotate and reflect the graph(also affect the labels)


g = GraphPlot[{2 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 3,
    5 -> 4}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {Left, Bottom}], 
  ImageSize -> {400, 200}]
g /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> 
  ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]@RotationMatrix[-(π/2)] . {x, y}



Or another style.

Clear[g];
 g = 
 GraphPlot[{2 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 3, 
   5 -> 4}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], ImageSize -> {400, 200}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> 
   Function[{p}, {Red, AbsolutePointSize[20], Point[p], White, 
     AbsolutePointSize[15], Point[p]}]]
g /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> 
  ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]@RotationMatrix[-(π/2)] . {x, y}


